# Creating a read only account for AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I would like to create a read only account for all of our RDS instances in AWS (PostGreSQL). I started by creating an IAM group and attached the AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess policy. I created a new IAM user and put him in this group. I cannot connect to our database with this new read only user (tested successfully with our admin account just fine). I now realize I don't have a read only user in the database itself. Which begs me three questions:

1. Is there any sense in creating a read-only IAM user for our RDS
   instances when I can create a read only DB user inside the database?
2. When I access the db via the commandline, ex. psql --host=servername --port=portnumber --username=username --password --dbname=databasename. This is the name of the DB user as I understand, so is there a point in creating a separate RDS IAM read
   only user?
3. If I have a read only IAM user for RDS, is there any danger they could still have write access if say someone else created a DB write
   account for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IAM users and DB users are 100% separated. One never affects the other and each serves different purposes.

**IAM users**

These users read/change/delete the servers using the AWS APIs. They cannot access or otherwise do anything with the *database* via the `psql` application.

IAM users can do the following:

- Create RDS instances
- Read information from the RDS instance
- Delete RDS instances
- Create and restore snapshots
- Modify RDS options and parameters

All the above are done using the AWS SDKs and CLI.

**DB users**

These users read/change/delete data in the database. They cannot manage or otherwise do anything with the RDS instance.

DB users can do the following:

- Select data
- Insert data
- Update data
- Delete data
- Create databases
- Managed other DB users

All the above are done using `psql` for example.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. This makes a whole lot of sense.